# Sql ExecuteSqlCommand to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

There's a way in LINQ to convert this following sql code ?

```
public Category SaveCategory(Category category, string tableName)
{  

     var context = new MyEntities();

     context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (title,description) VALUES {0}{1} ", table.title, table.description);
```

}

I want to avoid the use of conditions like "if" and "switch case" like :

```
 case "Country": tableName= db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
       break;
case "City": tableName= db.Cities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
       break;

...
return tableName
```

Comment: What type is `db` derived from? I'm assuming it's `DbContext` like [this example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/dbcontext-vs-objectcontext.aspx) has.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `Type`s instead of `string`s, you can use the [`Set` method of the `DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%28System.Type%29).

```
Type tableType = // type representing Country
DbSet mySet = db.Set(tableType);
mySet.Add(whatever);
```

Or you can access the [`Database` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database), but your code is potentially open to SQL injection. You should validate the string against a whitelist of valid table names, or do something else to remove the possibility of injection.

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(...);
```

Comment: If i use the db.Database i will not get objects in the case of a SELECT.

Comment: Oh, so you're trying to do this in more cases than just INSERTs. If much of your code is like the INSERT example, where you have the same simple (id, title, description) structure, maybe you should have a table for `Categories` and an enum that says whether the category is a Country, City, etc. instead of a separate table for each. As it is, it feels like you're trying to fit a round peg in a square hole by using LINQ like string-based SQL queries (because you have a bad DB-to-model design).

Comment: I prefer to have a separate table and then get data from one table at a time knowing that i will always use one table and not two or more. If i create a Category table that map all my Country, City tables i will end up with a huge table with thousand of data, plus i will have other table later with the same structure. So why fetching all the Europe to get Italy if i know that i just want to go to Italy ;) the db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(...) is the good solution for me. To avoid SQL Injection i will use something like : VALUES {0}{1} ", table.title, table.description. Thank you for your help

Comment: That's what indexes are for, generally speaking. But, I'm not sure you've got the right parameter format. Should be `@p0`, not `{0}`, from looking at [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: you have an idea how to do it with a LIKE %% ? ex : WHERE title LIKE '%@p0%', it always return null

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'd be `LIKE @p0` and then your value for that param would be `"%whatever%"`